# ls command in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, ls

I have to ls command to get the details of certain types of files. The file name has a specific format. The first two words followed by the date on which the file was generated

e.g.:

`Report_execution_032916.pdf`

`Report_execution_033016.pdf`

Word summary can also come in place of report.

e.g.:

`Summary_execution_032916.pdf`

Hence in my shell script I put these line of codes

```
DATE=`date +%m%d%y`
Model=Report
file=`ls ${Model}_execution_*${DATE}_*.pdf`
```

But the value of Model always gets resolved to 'REPORT' and hence I get:

```
ls: cannot access REPORT_execution_*032916_*.pdf: No such file or directory
```

I am stuck at how the resolution of Model is happening here.

I can't reproduce the exact code here. Hence I have changed some variable names. Initially I had used the variable name type instead of Model. But Model is the on which I use in my actual code

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). That being said, I don't see **why** `type` should turn to uppercase. Wait... your example filenames **don't** have a `.pdf` extension, while the `file=` line expects one...?!?

Comment: Are you sure what you posted is exactly what you have? The `$DATE` var shouldn't be expanded since your command is wrong (missing `$`). But your output indicates it is...

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. MY output files have the .pdf extension. I have modified the question accordingly and written the precise error which was thrown.

Comment: The code shown cannot result in the error shown, not without something else going on. Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducable example. (Ideally one that creates the expected file itself, e.g. via `touch <filename>`.)

Comment: @Mat I was wrong when Ipasted the code there was $ before date. I have modified the post

Comment: @AparnaRajan "Report" is still uppercase for some reason? You could make a variable after `type` that only holds the filepath + filename - just to separate things while you debug

Comment: You don't have underscores after the dates in the file names, but you attempt to put one there in the glob pattern.  Note that the glob `*` is different from a regex `*`; in globbing, `*` means zero or more of any character, and is equivalent to `.*` (more or less) in a normal regex.  What is the value of `${type}` in your shell?  Is it exported and read-only by any chance?  (It's possible to make a variable read-only, and export it; I don't think that the read-only status is inherited by a child process, though.  And attempts to modify a read-only variable trigger a warning.)

Comment: Basic debugging: what is the output from `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  If the script contains only those three lines, do you get the claimed behaviour?  What happens if you include `echo "[${type}]"` in your script after the `type=Report` line?  You should see `[Report]` but is that what you see?  Do you have a weird alias for `ls` somewhere?  What else have you got in your script?  In your `.bashrc` file?  Do you have something like [`declare -u type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) somewhere in the system?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
I have another script which runs before this. That script has the line typeset -u Model. I think this sets the Model always to upper case. Thanks

Comment: We won't be able to help much more until you include the output of `bash -x yourscript.sh` in the question.  You're seeing unusual behaviour — it is hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: @AparnaRajan Your last remark makes it clear your question does _not_ provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, I cannot even tell which shell you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed your script to use `Model=Report` and `${Model}` and you've said you have `typeset -u Model` in your script.  The `-u` option to the [`typeset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-typeset) command (instead of [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) — they're synonyms) means "convert the strings assigned to all upper-case".

> `-u` When the variable is assigned a value, all lower-case characters are converted to upper-case. The lower-case attribute is disabled.

That explains the upper-case `REPORT` in the variable expansion.  You can demonstrate by writing:

```
Model=Report
echo "Model=[${Model}]"
```

It would echo `Model=[REPORT]` because of the `typeset -u Model`.

- Don't use the `-u` option if you don't want it.

You should probably fix your glob expression too:

```
file=$(ls ${Model}_execution_*${DATE}*.pdf)
```

Using `$(…)` instead of backticks is generally a good idea.

And, as a general point, learn how to [Debug a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/951352#951352) and always provide an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so that we can see what your problem is more easily.

Comment: Thanks,It helped. And thanks for you suggestions. I am quite a beginner to stack exchange as well as unix shell scripting. I will definitely keep in mind these points.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to look at:

- `type` is usually a reserved word, though it won't break your script, I suggest you to change that variable name to something else.
- You are missing an `$` before `{DATE}`, and you have an extra `_` after it. If the date is the last part of the name, then there's no point in having an `*` at the end either. The `file` definition should be:

`` file=`ls ${type}_execution_*${DATE}.pdf` ``

Try debugging your code by parts: instead of doing an `ls`, do an `echo` of each variable, see what comes out, and trace the problem back to its origin.

As @DevSolar [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286706/ls-command-in-unix#comment60199132_36286706) you may have problems parsing the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround

```
ls | grep `date +%m%d%y` | grep "_execution_" | grep -E 'Report|Summary'
```

filters the `ls` output afterwards.

```
touch 'Summary_execution_032916.pdf'
DATE=`date +%m%d%y`
Model=Summary
file=`ls ${Model}_execution_*${DATE}*.pdf`
```

worked just fine on

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Part of question: 
But the value of Model always gets resolved to 'REPORT' and hence I get:
```

This is due to the fact that in your script you have exported Model=Report

```
Part of question:
ls: cannot access REPORT_execution_*032916_*.pdf: No such file or directory
```

No such file our directory issue is due to the additional "_" and additional "*"s that you have put in your 3rd line. 
Remove it and the error will be gone. Though, Model will still resolve to Report

Original 3rd line :

```
 file=`ls ${Model}_execution_*${DATE}_*.pdf`
```

Change it to

```
 file=`ls ${Model}_execution_${DATE}.pdf`
```

Above change will resolve the could not found issue.

```
Part of question
I am stuck at how the resolution of Model is happening here.
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to populate the file parameter with file name with anything_exection_someDate.pdf, then you can write your script as

```
DATE=`date +%m%d%y`
file=`ls *_execution_${DATE}.pdf`

If you echo the value of file you will get 
Report_execution_032916.pdf Summary_execution_032916.pdf
as the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some other scripts which were invoked before the control reaches the line of codes which I mentioned in the question. In one such script there is a code 
    typeset -u Model 
This sets the value of the variable model always to uppercase which was the reason this error was thrown
   ls: cannot access REPORT_execution_*032916_*.pdf: No such file or directory

I am sorry that 
i couldn't provide a minimal,complete and verifiable code